# PCI serial card won't talk on Linux system?

Tags: linux, drivers, motherboard, pci-express, serial-port

I am running Mageia Linux and I have a PCI card with 2 serial ports and my motherboard (ASUS H81M-A) doesn't have any onboard serial port. The PCI card is manufactured by WCH it seems. I tried to install the Linux Driver that came with the card, but my system found bunch of errors in them files and quit installing the driver. My card looks like this and it has CH3825SP@1107 right on it.
[image]

So, I started looking for help online and found some information that to do the following.

I ran `lspci -v` and got this. I believe the section with `Serial controller` is my PCI serial card.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7e14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7e1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at f7e1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8576
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: df200000-df3fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000df400000-00000000df5fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0100000-00000000f01fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7e1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7e1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at f7e19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

03:00.0 Serial controller: Device 1c00:3253 (rev 10) (prog-if 05 [16850])
    Subsystem: Device 1c00:3253
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0100000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=32K]
    I/O ports at e100 [size=4]
    Expansion ROM at f7d00000 [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8554
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

And then ran this command `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A` to set Port `ttyS0` to the PCI card. According to the blog posts([Serial-Port-Work-Linux](https://www.placona.co.uk/359/linux/getting-serial-ports-to-work-on-linux/) and [electronics FAQ](http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2010/02/getting-serial-port-to-work-under.html)) I found online, this all I have to do to use my serial PCI card. However, it doesn't work. Once I run the `setserial` command, my program can't get access to `ttyS0`. I don't know what I am doing or how to get this to work. Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the dmesg for PCI. Sorry if it is too long. :)

```
[    0.209051] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.214664] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-3e]
[    0.214665] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.214666] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.214667] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.214668] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    0.214669] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.214670] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.214670] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff]
[    0.214671] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff]
[    0.214672] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff]
[    0.214673] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xdf200000-0xfeafffff]
[    0.214678] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:0c00] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.214730] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:0c01] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.214754] pci 0000:00:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.214782] pci 0000:00:01.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.214806] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:041e] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.214813] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7800000-0xf7bfffff 64bit]
[    0.214817] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.214820] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0xf000-0xf03f]
[    0.214865] pci 0000:00:03.0: [8086:0c0c] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.214870] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e14000-0xf7e17fff 64bit]
[    0.214936] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:8c31] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.214950] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e00000-0xf7e0ffff 64bit]
[    0.214999] pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.215020] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215042] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:8c3a] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.215057] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e1e000-0xf7e1e00f 64bit]
[    0.215110] pci 0000:00:16.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215159] pci 0000:00:1a.0: [8086:8c2d] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.215176] pci 0000:00:1a.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e1c000-0xf7e1c3ff]
[    0.215253] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215284] pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215307] pci 0000:00:1b.0: [8086:8c20] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.215319] pci 0000:00:1b.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e10000-0xf7e13fff 64bit] 
[    0.215376] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215399] pci 0000:00:1b.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215418] pci 0000:00:1c.0: [8086:8c10] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.215474] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215498] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215518] pci 0000:00:1c.1: [8086:8c12] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.215573] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215597] pci 0000:00:1c.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215616] pci 0000:00:1c.2: [8086:8c14] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.215671] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215695] pci 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215722] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:8c26] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.215739] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e1b000-0xf7e1b3ff]
[    0.215813] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215844] pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.215866] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:8c5c] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.215991] pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:8c02] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.216003] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [io  0xf0b0-0xf0b7]
[    0.216008] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x14: [io  0xf0a0-0xf0a3]
[    0.216013] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x18: [io  0xf090-0xf097]
[    0.216019] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x1c: [io  0xf080-0xf083]
[    0.216024] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x20: [io  0xf060-0xf07f]
[    0.216029] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf7e1a000-0xf7e1a7ff]
[    0.216059] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.216096] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:8c22] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.216107] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7e19000-0xf7e190ff 64bit]
[    0.216122] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [io  0xf040-0xf05f]
[    0.216188] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.216234] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.216299] pci 0000:03:00.0: [1c00:3253] type 00 class 0x070005
[    0.216321] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff]
[    0.216334] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xf0100000-0xf0107fff pref]
[    0.216347] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xe100-0xe103]
[    0.216397] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7d07fff pref]
[    0.216467] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.216491] pci 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.218233] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[    0.218235] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.218237] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7dfffff]
[    0.218241] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf0100000-0xf01fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.218298] pci 0000:04:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.218315] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xd000-0xd0ff]
[    0.218340] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xf7c00000-0xf7c00fff 64bit]
[    0.218355] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf0003fff 64bit pref]
[    0.218441] pci 0000:04:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.218442] pci 0000:04:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.218469] pci 0000:04:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.220231] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 04] 
[    0.220233] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.220235] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf7c00000-0xf7cfffff]
[    0.220239] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf0000000-0xf00fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.222384] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    0.234605] pci 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02] add_size 1000
[    0.234607] pci 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 02] add_size 200000
[    0.234609] pci 0000:00:1c.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 02] add_size 200000
[    0.234620] pci 0000:00:1c.0: res[14]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] get_res_add_size add_size 200000
[    0.234621] pci 0000:00:1c.0: res[15]=[mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] get_res_add_size add_size 200000
[    0.234622] pci 0000:00:1c.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
[    0.234626] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0xdf200000-0xdf3fffff]
[    0.234630] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0xdf400000-0xdf5fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.234631] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.234633] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.234637] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.234639] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.234642] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdf200000-0xdf3fffff]
[    0.234644] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdf400000-0xdf5fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.234648] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[    0.234649] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.234652] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7dfffff]
[    0.234655] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf0100000-0xf01fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.234658] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[    0.234660] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.234663] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf7c00000-0xf7cfffff]
[    0.234665] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf0000000-0xf00fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.234669] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.234670] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.234671] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.234672] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    0.234673] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.234674] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.234675] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff]
[    0.234676] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff]
[    0.234676] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 12 [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff]
[    0.234677] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 13 [mem 0xdf200000-0xfeafffff]
[    0.234679] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.234679] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xdf200000-0xdf3fffff]
[    0.234680] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xdf400000-0xdf5fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.234681] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.234682] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7dfffff]
[    0.234683] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xf0100000-0xf01fffff 64bit pref]  
[    0.234684] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.234685] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xf7c00000-0xf7cfffff]
[    0.234686] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xf0000000-0xf00fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.235106] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM
[    0.326884] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.326887] pcie_pme 0000:00:01.0:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.326897] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    0.326899] pcie_pme 0000:00:1c.0:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.326909] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.326910] pci 0000:03:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.326912] pcie_pme 0000:00:1c.1:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.326922] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.326923] pci 0000:04:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    0.326925] pcie_pme 0000:00:1c.2:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.326929] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.326953] pciehp 0000:00:1c.0:pcie04: Slot #0 AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- PwrCtrl- MRL- Interlock- NoCompl+ LLActRep+
[    0.326972] pciehp 0000:00:1c.0:pcie04: service driver pciehp loaded
[    0.326974] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.361643] pci 0000:00:1f.0: hash matches
[    2.542045] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    2.542241] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.542248] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.542260] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    2.546158] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.546221] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: irq 20, io mem 0xf7e1c000
[    2.551740] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00  
[    2.552041] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.552045] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.552054] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    2.555948] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.555961] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf7e1b000
[    2.561726] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.853629] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.863611] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    3.419557] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0001/input/input6
[    3.471559] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0002/input/input7
[    8.630309] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input8
[    8.747637] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input10
[    8.747685] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input11
[    8.747730] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input12
[    8.747785] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input13
[    8.747848] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that support for your card was added recently this [year](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg21083.html). If the kernel is new enough, you should check if the kernel module is loaded with

> lsmod

if not, you should load it with

> sudo modprobe serial_cs

Comment: Also, have a look at dmesg/syslog after boot resp. the modprobe to see if the driver recognizes the card, or if there are any problems.

Comment: I did find out that serial_cs wasn't loaded and did load it through modprobe. I did find a most recent driver on the internet for a similar pci serial card and was able to install it successfully. However, it created its own serial FILE (ttyWCH01 and ttyWCH1) instead of using ttyS0 ... Anyways, my program still not able to talk through the PCI card. Plus, my program uses ttyS0 ... ttyS3 for connection.

Comment: @dirkt I did see bunch of lines related pci, but I couldn't tell if any of them are related to my pci serial card.

Comment: Can you upload syslog/dmesg somewhere and post a link?

Comment: Also, as soon as it works, it may be a good idea to add some `udev` rules that create symlinks with logical names for the ports, and change your program to use these instead of ttyS0...ttyS3.

Comment: I agree with @dirk, you should modify udev rules in order to force the driver to create ttyS0 instead of ttyWCH01

Comment: Awesome! I actually tested my PCI serial through terminal program using ttyWCH0 and it works and now I need to route communication to ttyS0 from ttyWCH0. I only wish I knew how to work with udev and create symlinks. could you guys give me an example?

Comment: You have a great tutorial in the ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev

Comment: @DrNoone Since you mentioned that they've added support for this card recently, I reinstalled my whole system and updated it. After installing setserial command from the repository, I simply executed `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A` in the terminal. My program just started to communicate.